# Header View for a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I want to have a custom view at the top of my UITextView that will scroll with the text view, so it is only visible when the text view is scrolled to the very top. Can this be done? I was thinking that because it is a subclass of UIScrollView there may be something that can be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `contentInset` / `contentOffset` / `contentSize` properties, inherited from [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)?