# iPhone iOS how to add a visible a header view to UITextView above text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, header, uitextview

I'm trying to add a header over a UITextView. The code that I have right now adds a header, which is visible initially, but it becomes hidden as soon as the user scrolls (it has pull down to refresh feel to it). 
**I'm looking to make my UITextView draw text 90 pixels lower than normal, and draw the header above text, starting at the origin. How can this be done?**

Currently I have:

```
[self.textViewWithHeader addSubview:self.headerView];
self.headerView.center = CGPointMake(160,-50);
self.salesCopyTextField.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,-90);
```

This shows a header over text, but it is clipped off by the bounds of the scrollview.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a plain `UITableView` with the first cell being a header. The second cell includes a UITextView with it's height dynamically calculated to match the height of the `UITextView`. The `UITextView` has scrolling disabled, only leaving the `UITableView's` scrolling. There's a weird behavior of scrolling as the user taps the text view to edit it, but I don't think that's a major issue

Comment: You could also have used tableHeaderView and tableFooterView of the UITableView

Answer (score 1):

Using **Swift 3**:

```
let headerViewHeight: CGFloat = 30.0
let headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: textView.bounds.origin.x, y: textView.bounds.origin.y - headerViewHeight, width: textView.bounds.size.width, height: headerViewHeight))
textView.addSubview(headerView)
textView.contentInset.top = headerViewHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does self.headerView need to be a subview of self.textViewWithHeader?  I would instead add self.headerView to the parent view of textViewWithHeader in the appropriate location.

Something like

```
[self.view addSubview:self.textViewWithHeader];
self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.textViewWithHeader.frame.origin.x, self.textViewWithHeader.frame.origin.y - self.headerView.frame.size.height, self.headerView.frame.size.width, self.headerView.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:self.headerView];
```

Comment: I would like the header to be initially visible, but scrollable off-page. (As the user scrolls down, the text will take up full screen) If I just add it to the main view, it will always be visible and will always take up space.

Comment: Ahh ok, I mis-read your post.  To me, it sounded like it was unfavorable that it was scrolling off the page ("code that I have right now adds a header, which is visible initially, but it becomes hidden as soon as the user scrolls").  Can you provide an example of the behavior you are looking for?  Would it be how section headers function in a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Set [`contentInset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset) not [`contentOffset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset). `contentOffset` just affects the scroll position. For a good explanation of `contentOffset`, check out the beginning of "Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views" of the [WWDC 2012 Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/).

Related:
[Header View for a UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327881/header-view-for-a-uitextview)