# Android: Header View for a TextView?

Tags: java, android, header, textview

Hello i have the same question as this post : [Header View for a UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327881/header-view-for-a-uitextview) but then for android does someone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: keep in mind, UITextView != TextView in android. TextView in android == UILabel, means TextView is readonly representation of text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement a new custom `View` extending a `LinearLayout` for example. You can add attributes like the text and the customView you want to add. Did you try it ?

Here is the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for creating custom views, and there is a lot of tuts on google.

Comment: Can you give me an example i am new to java?